# How to program an 8086 microprocessor?

Tags: x86-16

There are millions of tutorials about how to program an 8086 microconputer in assembly but none of them explains how to get the program file to the memory? I assume i have to get the hex file to the memory but how? Where do I get a programmer?

Comment: It really depends on your target hardware, how it's connected to your development system, and whether the target system has some kind of loader or other firmware in place.

Comment: That's what that row of switches on the front panel is for.

Answer (score 1):

you code in assembly language, and you assemble the assembly language to binary code with the assembler.
Yep, that was a lot of usage of the word "assemb..."

Wiki can get you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_assemblers a list of all 80x86 cpus... personally I would choose GAS and use a tutorial for that.

Maybe you want to have a look at "Programming from the Ground UP" (PGU) which uses gas and can be read online here http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/pgubook/ (google gave me the link)